# xTabs with Cbind - split reported values up into sub categories

Tags: r

Using the following code

xtabs(cbind(violentIncidents, nonviolentIncidents, allPart1s) ~
District + pnum, data = cadincmerge_ag4wk)

[image]

This combines violentIncidents, nonviolentIncidents, allPart1s into one total, however, how can I get it split up by pnum so that it looks like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please show a small reprodcuible example with `dput`

Comment: I get an array with a similar code `xtabs(cbind(cyl, gear, carb) ~ vs + am, mtcars)`

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);mtcars %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(vs, am)) %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(across(c(cyl, gear, carb), sum))`

Comment: It looks promising but R tells me -- Error in across(c(cyl, gear, carb), sum) : 
  could not find function "across"

Answer (score 0):

If we need to summarise multiple groups on multiple columns, we can use `tidyverse`.  Reshape the data into 'long' format with `pivot_longer` using the grouping columns, then grouped by the column name, 'value' get teh `sum` of columns with `across`

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = c(vs, am)) %>% 
     group_by(name, value) %>%
     summarise(across(c(cyl, gear, carb), sum))
```

Comment: It looks promising but R tells me -- Error in across(c(cyl, gear, carb), sum) : 
  could not find function "across"

Comment: @user13203033 it is from `dplyr` 1.0.0

Comment: @user13203033 if. you have an earlier version of `dplyr`, instead of `summarise(across` use `summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), sum)`